# How to create calendar with specified periods in jsf/myfaces? is it possible?

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces

I`m preparing application where user can book a room for specified period. I want to show user a calendar where he will be able to select start and end date of his reservation, but i also want to markup the days in which the room has already been reserved. Is it possible using jsf/myfaces?

Answer (score 1):

[You can directly use one ready made in rich faces, why to re invent wheel](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=organizer&cid=36988)

Answer (score 0):

Just Use a Ice Faces so you can directly use a ready made calendar.

< ice:selectInputDate id="fromDateId" renderMonthAsDropdown="true" renderYearAsDropdown="true" value="#{slowMovingSalesOrderAction.fromDate}" title="#{msgs['page.selectInputDate.popup.title']}" renderAsPopup="true" tabindex="1">

```
            < f:convertDateTime pattern="#{productionRegisterAction.systemDateFormat}" timeZone="#{productionRegisterAction.timeZone}"/>

          < /ice:selectInputDate>
```